# Antiderivative of $xe^{-cx^2}$

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

I need to define $c$ in $$\int_0^\infty xe^{-cx^2},$$ so that it becomes a probability-mass function (so that it equals 1).

Where do I even begin finding the antiderivative of this? I know the answer will be: $\frac{e^{-cx^2}}{-2c}$

Trying to use partial integration: $$\int f(x)g(x) dx = f(x)G(x) - \int f'(x)G(X)$$ and picking $x$ as my $g(x)$, and $e^{-cx^2}$ as my $f(x)$ I end up with:

$f'(x) = -2cxf(x)$

$G(X) = \frac{x^2}{2}$

$$e^{-cx^2} \frac{x^2}{2} - \int_0^\infty -2cxf(x)\frac{x^2}{2} dx$$

Which simplifies to:

$$e^{-cx^2} \frac{x^2}{2} - \int_0^\infty -cx^4 e^{-cx^2} dx$$

, which I find is just a mess.

Comment: Hint: Try differentiating $f(x)=e^{-cx^2}$. You should be able to integrate it (probably from 0 to $\infty$) and then set $c$ appropriately

Comment: Come on, you even have the solution given to you... Just compute the derivative of the proposed solution, and see if it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The antiderivative is easy. Note that ,since you want the integral to equal $1$ :

$$\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-cx^2}\, {\rm d}x =1 &\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{2c}\int_{0}^{\infty} 2c xe^{-cx^2}\, {\rm d}x =1 \\ 
 &\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{2c}\left [ -e^{-cx^2} \right ]_0^{\infty}=1\\ 
 &\Leftrightarrow 2c = 1\\ 
 &\Leftrightarrow c=1/2
\end{align*}$$

Note also that $c$ must be positive , otherwise the integral won't converge.

**Update:** I fixed a major blunder. The quantity in brackets is evaluated as follows:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}2c x e^{-cx^2}\, {dx} = -\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} e^{-cx^2} + e^0 = 1 $$

(which is the definition of improper integral) and hence we go on to solve the equation.

Comment: Why is $1/2c = 2c$?

Comment: Oups. Let me change that.

Answer (score 0):

for $f(x)=e^{-cx^2}$ you have $f'(x)=-2cxf(x)$, so integration by parts gives
$\int xf(x)dx = \frac{1}{-2c}\int f'(x)dx=\frac{1}{-2c}f(x)+C$.

now the definite integral.

to have a probability-mass function, $c$ has to be positive (otherwise the limit in infinity is intinite) and then 
$1=\int xf(x)dx = \frac{1}{-2c}f(x)|_0^{\infty}=\frac{1}{-2c}(0-1)$, so $c=\frac{1}{2}$ is the only solution.

hope it helps.